# After installing exercism.io my terminal looks weird

Tags: shell

I installed exercism in my path with this command

```
echo 'export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

but after restarting my system, I cant access nvm and other aliases I made. If I source .bashrc then my shell goes back to normal.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use caution when putting `~/bin` at the front of your `PATH`.  It's moderately difficult to add malicious programs to the other directories in your `PATH` as they're only writable by the `root` user, but `~/bin` is in your home directory.  Consider adding `~/bin` to the end of your `PATH`.

Comment: @ctt   `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` I changed it to this and sourced it but still cant get back my old shell with all those aliases

Comment: This tip was not an answer to your question, but more some sage advice to prevent you from trolling yourself.  To answer your question, it may help if you edit your question with snippets of which commands no longer work, and details on how they're setup.  For example, which of your shell configuration files is `nvm`'s helper script sourced?